# Скрипт для просчета формулы jasper report

Tags: java, jasperreports

Как преобразовать данную переменную из `string'a` в `double`, для последующего ее умножения и деления.

```
net.homecredit.tools.Ft.formatCurrency(  
 new Double(  
  ($F{annuityProc} != null ? $F{annuityProc}.doubleValue() * ($F{creditAmount}.doubleValue())  
   :  
    ($F{annuityTypeTxt} != null ? $F{annuityTypeTxt}.doubleValue() * ($F{creditAmount}.doubleValue()) : "Данных нет")  
     /100  
      ))  
,"#,##0.00")+" руб."
```

`$F{annuityProc}` переменная `double`.
`$F{creditAmount}` переменная `double`.
`$F{annuityTypeTxt}` переменная `string`.

Необходимо `$F{annuityProc}` умножить на `$F{creditAmount}` и разделить сумму на 100.
Если `$F{annuityProc}` на входе `null`, то необходимо `$F{annuityTypeTxt}` умножить на `$F{creditAmount}` и сумму разделить на 100.

Ошибку выводит:

> The method doubleValue() is undefined for the type String

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам.

```
net.homecredit.tools.Ft.formatCurrency(
new Double(
 ((($F{annuityProc}).doubleValue()
  *
   ($F{creditAmount}).doubleValue())
    /100)
     ))
```